# how to make one widget as master in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I just made a flutter project.
how to make one expandable as master then the content can change according to what we call

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB5He.jpg)

what I mean is something like this:

```
main () {
body: column [
myMasterExpand (mycontent1 ()),
myMasterExpand (mycontent2 ()),
];
}

class myMasterExpand () {}

class mycontent1 () {}
class mycontent2 () {}
```

Comment: you can use `ExpansionTile` for `mycontent2`.

Comment: that's not what I meant sir. I have content1 containing form1 and content2 containing form2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a widget like this as your master:

```
class MyMasterExpandable extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget content;

  const MyMasterExpandable({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.content})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(title),
      children: [content],
    );
  }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
MyMasterExpandable(title: 'My Title', content: content1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! this is very helpful and solve my problem

Comment: @Arifhidayah Glad to hear that! Thank you for accepting my answer.